# CMake: what is the purpose of matching a variable against itself?

Tags: cmake

I saw the following piece of CMake code in the definition of the [CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES macro](http://sewm.pku.edu.cn/src/paradise/thirdparty/installed/share/cmake-2.6/Modules/CheckCSourceCompiles.cmake):

```
IF("${VAR}" MATCHES "^${VAR}$")
...
```

What is the purpose of this code and wouldn't it always succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-July/030544.html)

> this is definitely not always true.
>   The variable your are testing may contain "un-evaluated" var
>   or some special regex character( *, ?, ...)

Comment: Thanks for giving a link to the thread. From that I've found out that this was a hack to check if the variable is not defined, so modern CMake equivalent should be "if(NOT DEFINED VAR)".